# Cannot find the calendar webpart or list! Where can I find it?

Tags: calendar

I have a sharepoint 2010 portal and I would like to create a new web template. The site template is a publishing template. When I click on new site I see the home page. I would like to add the calendar webpart or list, but I cannot find it in the webparts or lists. Is this because I have used the publising site template? Do I need to use explicit another site template where the calendar webpart or list is available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Activate following features in site settings will let you create a calender list which will be displayed as webpart you might need to change view but I didn't needed to,

- Office SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features
- Office SharePoint Server Standard Site features
- Team Collaboration Lists

For more Information check this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/4a91af21-06ee-46ab-9b10-89063311d689) out.

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: I have activate the features, but still cannot not see the calendar webpart. Where can I find it, in webparts or lists?

Comment: its a list and I added screenshot, http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/54db21/calendar-in-sharepoint-2010-programmatically-using-vs-2012/

Comment: I'm using Sharepoint 2013 and i did exactly what Muhammad Raja said , but my Calendar still not available.

Comment: Forget about it, i made a mistake. I comment a code of my  master page and that was the reason. Your Answer works perfectly.

Answer (score -4):

Here is also the answer:

http://sensoft2000-sharepoint.blogspot.nl/2011/07/issue-calendar-list-is-missing-in.html

activate the feature: team collaboration lists

Comment: Check my answer I told you to activate team collaboration lists feature already !

Comment: In the mean time I has found the same solution..

Comment: It's not about who find answer first, its about if there is a post which already answered the question then one shouldn't post a duplicate post, I hope you get my point :)